# Error 403 while trying to download the app via App Distribution

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-app-distribution, app-distribution

For testing, a project was created in Firebase and two applications (for iOS and Android) were published. Testers have also been added, who have successfully received invitations to participate in testing by email.

When clicking on the link in the invitation, a window opens (first screenshot), which successfully displays some information about the application under test. Immediately, the user is offered to download the App Tester application or download the application being tested directly. When you click on both buttons, the same error appears (second screenshots).

ps What can it be connected with? I am currently in Russia, but I tried downloading using a VPN - the same result.

pss the application is written in Flutter, it was also initialized as a Flutter application in Firebase
[image: info about app][image: 403 error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the download does not start due to the fact that I am geographically located in Russia, which is sad. The download has started from the VPN of another country.

ps Apparently the VPN, under which the application did not load, also sent requests through Russia